# Segment measure in right triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The $\triangle ABO$ is rectangle in $O$, $OA=a$ and $OB=b$, if $AP=PQ=QB=x$, then $x=?$

[image]

I tried pythagoras in $\triangle POQ$, because $OP=a-x$, $OQ=b-x$ and $PQ=x$ and got a messy equation that i can't solve. That's what i tried for now.

Comment: Edited. I put what i tried.

Comment: Show us the "messy" equation. Otherwise we don't really know what you tried and we don't know how close you were to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can solve it easily, this being a quadratic. Some terms even cancel out nicely:
$$(a-x)^2+(b-x)^2=x^2$$
$$x^2-2(a+b)x+a^2+b^2=0$$
$$x=\frac{2(a+b)\pm\sqrt{4(a+b)^2-4(a^2+b^2)}}2$$
$$x=a+b-\sqrt{2ab}$$
We reject $+$ in the last line because $PQ$ can never be longer than $a+b$.

Comment: That was the trick, thanks.